# type error when casting sting type to integer type using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I write code to achieve the effect like that if you write 123 then return 321, if -123 then return -321. However, after I finished the code and try to run it the sentence of   | int = -int(rev_str) |   gives me the error saying: "'int' object is not callable". I do not know why, please anyone help me. thank you so much and appreciate it.

```
def reverse_32_int(int):
    if (int < -(2**31)) or (int > 2**31 - 1):
        print('exceed 32-bit range')
    else:
        if int < 0:
            int = -int
            str_int = str(int)
            rev_str = str_int[::-1]
            int = -int(rev_str)
            return int
        elif int > 0:
            str_int = str(int)
            rev_str = str_int[::-1]
            int = int(rev_str)
            return int
        else:
            return 0

reverse_32_int(123)
```

Comment: you used `int` as variable in `def reverse_32_int(int)` - rename it. You can't have variable `int` and function `int()`.

Answer (score 2):

You used `int` as variable in `def reverse_32_int(int)`. You can't have variable `int` and function `int()`. Rename it.

I use variable `value` instead of `int`

```
def reverse_32_int(value):
    if (value < -(2**31)) or (value > 2**31 - 1):
        print('exceed 32-bit range')
    else:
        if value < 0:
            value = -value
            str_int = str(value)
            rev_str = str_int[::-1]
            value = -int(rev_str)
            return value
        elif value > 0:
            str_int = str(value)
            rev_str = str_int[::-1]
            value = int(rev_str)
            return value
        else:
            return 0

reverse_32_int(123)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot. However, can you explain in detail why I cannot use 'int' as a parameter name and function int() at the same time in one code?

Comment: Because the computer can use '()' to identify which one is parameter and which one is the function, I think.

Comment: in Pythone function name is also variable - it keeps access to function which converts string into integer. And you can't have two elements with the same name (global or local name). When you assing value to variable `int` (ie. `int = 1`) then it replaces variable which gives you access to function which convert string to integer. You can also assing function to another variable ie. `integer = int` and later use it `interger("1234")` or `show = print` and `show("Hello World")`